# skype 4.3.0.37 typing is slow on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype

I recently installed the latest skype from their website 4.3.0.37 , on my ubuntu laptop, (14.04) LTS. (from the debian package `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`)

and after a couple days, it turned slow on me.. when I type in the chat box, there is a serious lag, but not always. so, for example I can type "this is a test" and when I look down on the window it only says "this" and after a second or two "is a" appears then "test".

There is almost no load on the PC, nothing much else is running on the machine. I can not see anything in syslog, or anywhere.

do you have any suggestion where I can look for error logs, how to turn on more logging, or if anyone have seen/fixed the same?

Answer (score 3):

Please, check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505766/unable-to-see-recent-chats-in-skype-4-3/), it helped me:

Also I had a problem today with Skype version 4.2 for Ubuntu 64 bit. My solution for this was approximately this:

```
Download latest skype (skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb)
sudo apt-get remove skype --purge
sudo apt-get remove skype-bin --purge
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb

# this one will remove mess from old Skype installations (can be a real cause of Skype misbehaviour)
cd ~ && rm -r .Skype
```