# Unable to see Recent Chats in skype 4.3

Tags: skype

After upgrading to latest version (4.3.0.37) the skype no longer showing Recent chats. It is showing a small black box as shown in the bellow pic instead of chat list.

[image]

If I downgrade the version, I am not able to login Skype. How to make "Recent Chats" to show recent chat history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Quit skype
- Move away the `~/.Skype` folder
- Start skype without the previous history.

That worked for me, at least first. However, the problem with the disappeared *Recent chats* came back, so I had to redo the above...

It seems like a bug in the new skype client.

Comment: Thank you. This is ok after moving .skype from home folder but is there any way to shift chat history to new version?

Comment: @Jabir: Probably, but I don't know how. You may want to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to do it. You need to edit the main.db database file as follows:

```
$ sqlite3 main.db
update Messages 
set body_xml=substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'<files'),12)||
             substr(body_xml,0,instr(body_xml,'<files'))||
             substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'alt=')+5) 
where type=68 and body_xml not like '<file%';
.quit
```

(via https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/skype)